# SQL error converting data type datetime to smalldatetime?

Tags: c#, sql, datetime-format

In my SQL stored procedure:

```
@StartDate as smalldatetime,
@EndDate as smalldatetime
```

In my C# code:

```
StartDate = new DateTime(1901,01,01,00,00,00);
EndDate = new DateTime(2200,01,01,00,00,00);

var StartDate2 = StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
StartDate2 = DateTime.ParseExact(StartDate2, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate2);

var EndDate2 = EndDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
EndDate2 = DateTime.ParseExact(EndDate2, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(EndDate2);
```

The column is as a smalldatetime type in the db. I'm going round in the circles with this! whats the correct way to parse my Dates to the correct format for querying in the db?

UPDATE:
Changed code to this and worked fine.

```
SqlParameter parameter = daHoliday.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.SmallDateTime);
SqlParameter parameter2 = daHoliday.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.SmallDateTime);
parameter.Value = StartDate;
parameter2.Value = EndDate;
```

Comment: Don't convert them to string, just pass them as `DateTime` type object through Command Parameters.

Comment: That did it, thanks! Updated code to reflect!

Comment: Please just answer your own question, and then in two days you can accept it. It will cleanup the workflow for this question.

Comment: @neoistheone - or newhire could post the answer and receive the rep

Comment: Or @NewHire can post his comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't convert them to string, just pass them as `DateTime` type object through Command Parameters.

`DateTime` should never be converted to string to match format of data in database table. If the datatype in table is `DateTime` then its always better to pass the .Net framework `DateTime` object as parameter to command.